# Determine values of the constants a & b so the limit exists and is equal to f(2) in a piece-wise function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to determine the values of the constants a & b in a piece-wise function that has to satisfy these parameters:
The limit f(x) as x approaches 2 does exist and is equal to f(2)

The piece-wise part is:

$$
f(x)= { 
        a+bx      if x>2
        3             if x=2
        b-ax^2  if x<2$$

I have tried solving individually for both a and b, and can come up with a number of solutions that work for each part, but not for both parts.

Basically I know I need to get both functions to pass through the point (2,3) but I really don't know how to go about solving this. I tried using a substitution method, but I don't think I am doing it right as I end up with:

a=3
b=1

neither function passes through (2,3) with these. I'm just not sure how else to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve the following equations
$a+2b=3$ and $b-4a=3$ 
The solution is $a=\frac{-1}{3}$ and $b=\frac{5}{3}$

Comment: I did come up with those equations, I may be applying the substitution method incorrectly. I come up with a=3-2b and b=3+4a  at this point I try substituting something like a=3-2(3+4a) would that be correct?

Comment: Sure. Just carry on the calculation and you will end up with $a=\frac{-1}{3}$